# CSS file not showing in Chrome Network Tab, but appears in view source

Tags: css, caching, browser

I tried updating some CSS on my site but the updates were not reflected in the browser.

I refreshed my cache of course.

I viewed the source of the site and clicked the .css file link and was able to view the .css file. It does have my changes. Same when I download the file via FTP.

However, the file does not appear to load when I open the Inspector's Network tab and reload the page. I see bootstrap.min.css loading, but not my styles.css file.

Would anyone know what's happening?

Comment: @Nenotlep TBH I can't remember what exactly fixed this case. But you could check if your CMS is caching a copy of your css (sometimes the file name has a hash - random letters and numbers - at the end).

Or else, sometimes cPanel is set to cache .css as well.

Another thing might be that your site/cms needs a base url set.

Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

bro make sure you url is correct and filename to.
eg:

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url}}">

Comment: It is correct. I can even click the link from the raw HTML